# RSS (Receive Side Scaling) support on virtio vhost adapter

Tags: linux-kernel, virtio, vhost

I’m running KVM guest (debian buster, kernel v6.1.36) with vhost interfaces configured like this:

```
<interface type='bridge'>
  <mac address='52:54:00:b4:26:1b'/>
  <source bridge='ovsbr0'/>
  <virtualport type='openvswitch'>
    <parameters interfaceid='7002497c-4352-4da9-a686-c039135d5348'/>
  </virtualport>
  <target dev='eth1'/>
  <model type='virtio'/>
  <driver name='vhost' queues='8' rx_queue_size='1024' tx_queue_size='1024'/>
  <alias name='net1'/>
  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x07' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
</interface>
```

The guest node shows multiqueue support for the interface:

```
$ ethtool -l eth1
Channel parameters for eth1:
Pre-set maximums:
RX:             n/a
TX:             n/a
Other:          n/a
Combined:       8
Current hardware settings:
RX:             n/a
TX:             n/a
Other:          n/a
Combined:       8
```

But the incoming traffic is being processed by the only one queue:

```
$ ethtool -S eth1|egrep "rx_queue_._packets"
     rx_queue_0_packets: 0
     rx_queue_1_packets: 0
     rx_queue_2_packets: 0
     rx_queue_3_packets: 1187
     rx_queue_4_packets: 0
     rx_queue_5_packets: 0
     rx_queue_6_packets: 0
     rx_queue_7_packets: 1870640
```

I was told that RSS support is somewhat new for the virtio, but here we have 6.1.36 on guest VyOS system. Do you know guys if there is a way to tell whether RSS should be supported by virtio vhost adapters or not? And if yes - which kernel version or/and probably qemu version?

Thank you,
Alex